Are questions on applied fields of psychology allowed?
There are a large number of applied fields of psychology.
E.g.,

Industrial / Organisational Psychology
Educational Psychology
Health Psychology
Clinical Psychology
Neuropsychology
Forensic Psychology
Counselling Psychology
Sports Psychology

I think questions related to  these areas should be permitted on the basis that they are sub-disciplines of psychology, and the site is meant to encompass cognitive sciences (e.g.., cognitive science, psychology, and psychiatry).

How do others feel about questions related to areas of applied psychology?


These seem on-topic to me, especially considering we subsumed the Psychology proposal; implicitly all Psychology is in our scope.

Yes.
The "Psychology" and "Psychology and Psychiatry" proposals were merged with this one, so the content they would have covered should be allowed.
I think it's also important to encourage practitioners to engage with the research community (and vice-versa), so the "science" in Cognitive Science shouldn't exclude questions related to practical applications of the relevant content.
Finally, we want to attract experts so questions regarding their field of expertise must be allowed, obviously, but more to the point the content should be accessible to practitioners  otherwise relevant experts may be scared off.
